# Public Pair: change of applicant - when will the tab "application data" be updated?

Tags: assignment, applicant, public-pair, update

I have a question regarding a change of applicant filed with the USPTO. We have filed said assignment document in January 2019(!). This assignment document will be displayed in tab "Assignments" on Public Pair.

However, the first named applicant on tab "Application Data" still shows the former applicant.

My question is: when will the applicant on tab "Application Data" be updated to the current applicant?

Or will this change never be displayd on this tab because the tab "Application Data" only provides historical information about how the application was originally filed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applicant and assignee are not the same thing. To change the applicant you will need to file a "request to take action" from the new assignee and a new ADS. See MPEP

> 325 Establishing Right of Assignee To Take Action in Application Filed On or After September 16, 2012 [R-10.2019]

> An assignee who is not the original applicant must become the applicant
> under 37 CFR 1.46(a) in order to request or take action in a patent
> application. A request to change the applicant under 37 CFR 1.46(c)(2)
> must be filed and must be accompanied by an application data sheet
> under 37 CFR 1.76 specifying the applicant in the applicant
> information section and comply with 37 CFR 3.71 and 37 CFR 3.73.